How To CAST substring as a DATE
I have the following string:
2024-07-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
I wish to convert it to MM/dd/yyyy
I have tried the following SQL:
CAST (SUBSTRING(ESTIMATED_DISPATCH,1,4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(ESTIMATED_DISPATCH,6,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(ESTIMATED_DISPATCH,9,2) AS date) AS estimated_dispatch

I am getting the error:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can someone guide me on the correct way to convert this to a date

"convert it to MM/dd/yyyy", "convert this to a date", and what your code does ("yyyy/MM/dd") are three separate things. If you want to convert to a date, cast to a date. If you want to convert to a string in the format of MM/dd/yyyy, cast to a date and then format as MM/dd/yyyy.

if ESTIMATED_DISPATCH contains the date as you say then there is no error..https://dbfiddle.uk/DhFc_IDd and I can't reproduce your issue..(and it won't produce your desired outcome)

2024-07-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 is an unambiguous date format. Why not just CONVERT it? db<>fiddle as for the format to present it in, that's a presentation layer issue, not SQL.

As an aside, storing dates as a string is a bad design choice. It appears here you should be using a datetimeoffset.

@ThomA I wonder if he already is, but only see the string representation in ssms or other tool and doesn't realize.

Which, if that is the case @JoelCoehoorn , there's even more duplicates.

  DECLARE @InString VARCHAR(30)='2024-07-01T00:00:00.000+00:00';
  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),CAST(@InString AS DATE),101);

Please try this
